# Unit test for a function in C# using Moq

Tags: unit-testing, moq

I am trying to write unit tests for the below function in C# using Moq, but am finding slightly overwhelmed wrapping my head around verify, and other Moq concepts.

```
public X509Certificate GetCertificate(string certificateName)
        {
            var settingOverride = this.settings.SecretOverridesSetting.FirstOrDefault(secret => secret.Name.Equals(certificateName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
            if (settingOverride != null)
            {
                X509Certificate targetCertificate;
                var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
                store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
                X509Certificate2Collection certColl = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, settingOverride.Value, false);
                if (certColl.Count == 0)
                {
                    return null;
                }

                targetCertificate = certColl[0];
                store.Close();
                return targetCertificate;
            }
            else
            {
                return SecretStoreClientHelper.GetCertificate(certificateName);
            }
        }
```

This is my very first time writing a unit test for a function, in any language.
Could some one help me with a few unit test scenarios, of where I can use Moq.

Comment: For the first time write tests without Moq or any other mocking frameworks. Plain c# code.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to refactor this code in a way that it's not tightly coupled with any implementation. Because you can not mock non virtual methods of classes using MOQ.

Kindly refer the link https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart for more details on creating test methods using MOQ.